# GWT RPC attribute empty

Tags: gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

In my GWT app, have to track changes made to my hibernate objects, so I have this simple POJO to transfer modifications to the server side, where they would be logged:

```java
public class ModifiedValueReference implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6144012539285913980L;

    private Serializable oldValue;
    private Serializable newValue;

    public ModifiedValueReference() {
        super();
    }

    public ModifiedValueReference(Serializable oldValue, Serializable newValue) {
        this();
        setOldValue(oldValue);
        setNewValue(newValue);
    }

    public Serializable getOldValue() {
        return oldValue;
    }

    public void setOldValue(Serializable oldValue) {
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
    }

    public Serializable getNewValue() {
        return newValue;
    }

    public void setNewValue(Serializable newValue) {
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

}
```

The attributes `oldValue` and `newValue` are of type `Serializable` so my Integers, Strings, Dates, and Booleans can be stored, as well as several other Hibernate objects.

Tracking is achieved by using a special setter method that logs the modification (eg: by using `setFirstNameLog()` instead of `setFirstName()` below):

```java
public class Person {

    private String firstname;

    private Map<String, ModifiedValueReference> modifications = 
            new HashMap<String, ModifiedValueReference>(15);

    public void addModification(String key, Serializable oldValue, Serializable newValue) {
        if (key != null && !key.isEmpty()) {
            modifications.put(key, 
                    new ModifiedValueReference(oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }

    public void setFirstnameLog(String firstname) {
        addModification("First Name", getFirstname(), firstname);
        setFirstname(firstname);
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;     
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }
}
```

When the `ModifiedValueReference` object reaches the server side via GWT RPC, the `oldValue` and `newValue` are empty! **Why?**

Those fields were filled with Strings on the client side. On the server side, they are not null, but empty Strings.

Comment: Maybe some more code would help. Maybe the actual service call and the server side implementation.

Comment: @enrybo thanks for the suggestion. Since that code is at work, I made a sample GWT project at home to try to reproduce the issue. My code at home worked fine, so I suspect some other code at work is causing the issue. We have hibernate and gilead at work, so anything might be causing the issue. If you would like, I can post the code I wrote now.

Comment: @enrybo, I figured it out. I didn't have a setter for `modifications`, which caused it to not be reconstructed by GWT RPC on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `modifications` map in my `Person` class did not have a setter method (eg: A `setModifications(Map<String, ModifiedValueReference>)` method).

Because of this, GWT RPC was unable to reconstruct the map on the server side when a `Person` object was saved via a RPC method.

Comment: That's really strange because GWT serialization does not require getters or setters. All non-final,non-transient fields that are themselves serializable will be serialized.

Comment: @Strelok, I didn't think so either, but `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.deserializeClass(Class<?>, Object)`, which calls  `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.getSetters(Class<?>)` said otherwise. I figured it out as I was debugging everything that happens after `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(String)`.

Comment: Thanks! Wasted so much time because of the missing setter!

Comment: @Carcamano awesome! Good to know answers from over 3 years ago are still helping people!